# what is the similarity and difference between editable and readonly in javascript or extended java script?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

Please define the similarity or difference between '`readonly`' and '`editable`' of java script/extended java script.
Eg: if I declare `readOnly: true` and `editable: false` or vice versa, for any combo box,in ext-js, then how that combo will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as described in API documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-editable

> **editable:** False to prevent the user from typing text directly into the field;
>   the field can only have its value set via selecting a value from the
>   picker. In this state, the picker can also be opened by clicking
>   directly on the input field itself.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-readOnly

> **readOnly:** true to prevent the user from changing the field, and hides the trigger.  Supercedes the editable and hideTrigger options if the value is true.